# Adding one day to a date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I have looked at similar threads but nothing seems to have my answer. Here is what I have.

```
FDTMDUEDATE+1   >= Rundate
```

It brings me this error: 
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

If I do

```
FDTMDUEDATE-1  >= Rundate
```

It will work without issue. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: What data type is `FDTMDUEDATE` ?

Comment: fdtmDueDate Date/Time '9999-12-31'

Comment: That's not an Oracle [data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6)

Comment: `'9999-12-31'` is max value for dates in Oracle. You can add one day to date `'9999-12-30'` but if you try to do it with `'9999-12-31'` you get `ORA-01841`. You can check it in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52aaeddd67b6a7e0490fa3c450fafe35).

Comment: Could you please do a `DESC <table name>` on SQLPlus and paste the results back?

Comment: So the due date was 1/23/2020   It gets converted from our system (Where starts as 9999-12-31)     If i did duedate - 1 I would get 1/22/2020 but if I did rundate + 1 it would give me that error.  I just changed my query to DueDate < rundate since I want this to happen on the day after the due date (any day after the that will not hit again thanks to the rest of my query) but i am till curious why -1 works but not plus 1.

Comment: Add a day to 1/23/2020 does also work - [see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1468353802b0b4dc19ae9da6c2293635). What does "Where starts as 9999-12-31" mean? If you actually have that value and try to add a day to *that* then it will throw that error, as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `1` to an Oracle date does work as expected, ie it does add one day to the date :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2019-01-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) + 1 tomorrow FROM DUAL;
```

```
| TOMORROW  |
| :-------- |
| 30-JAN-19 |
```

However, as explained in [the Date Data Types documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) :

> Valid date range from January 1, 4712 BC, to December 31, 9999 AD.

In your use case it is likely that you are hitting the upper limit, as demonstrated in this statement :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) + 1 out_of_range FROM DUAL;
```

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Adding 1 day to `'9999-12-31'` causes the date to go out of the allowed range, causing error `ORA-01841`.

It does not look like a normal situation that you are processing such far future dates, and you would probably need to investigate why.

In the meantime, you should be able to workaround the issue by rewritting this :

```
FDTMDUEDATE + 1 >= Rundate
```

To :

```
FDTMDUEDATE >= Rundate - 1
```

(Unless, of course, `Rundate` is equal to  January 1, 4712 BC...)

Comment: Not every link returned by Google while searching for "Oracle" refers to a database. Link & info you posted is related to data **warehouse**, not the database itself. Valid date range is from January 1, 4712 BC, to December 31, 9999 AD, as stated in Data Types (ver. 12c), https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: @Littlefoot : ahh yes, sorry about that, I fixed the answer accordingly.